# Java Development Kit execution error in terminal

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

I just installed the Java SE Development Kit on my macbook pro, and when I subsequently run the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`in the terminal, I get the error message: `Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`.

When I try to check my java version with the command `java -version`, I get the error message: `Unrecognized option: - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

What does this error mean? I tried Googling the issue, and I could not find anyone with this exact issue for some reason. Do I need to reinstall it? According to most guides, installing the Development Kit ought to be super straight forward, and it should not cause errors like this.

Comment: You have to set the JAVA_HOME variable in your path. For more details check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux) link.